# tsql order by with distinct for xml path

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot, sql-order-by, distinct

I have a query that I use later to do a dynamic pivot. I'd like to order this query before doing the distinct. How could I achieve this? Whenever I order this it breaks the distinct completely.

```
    DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max);
SET @cols = STUFF
(
    (SELECT distinct ',' + c.[PivotColumnTitle]
        FROM [myTable] c
        WHERE c.Id = @idInput
        AND c.IsPivotVisible = 1
              --order by c.PivotColumnOrder
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,''
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(max);

SET @cols = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + c.[PivotColumnTitle]
        FROM [myTable] c
        WHERE c.Id = @idInput
            AND c.IsPivotVisible = 1
        GROUP BY c.[PivotColumnTitle]
        order by MAX(c.PivotColumnOrder)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,''
)
```